# Laravel Navigation Menu Setup Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am doing a blog project using Laravel, Livewire, Blade. I have a problem creating the navigation bar having "Dashboard", "Post", "Page", "Contact Us" in the same line as in picture 2.

The navigation I am having right now looks like in picture 1 which only "Dashboard", "Posts", "Pages" in the same line, and "Contact Us" are in a different line.  Even the "Dashboard" is in the same line but the space between is larger than the space between "Posts", "Pages". Can someone help me to fix it?

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

[image]

navigation-menu.blade.php

```
<nav x-data="{ open: false }" class="bg-white border-b border-gray-100">
<!-- Primary Navigation Menu -->
<div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="flex justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
                <a href="{{ route('posts') }}">
                    <x-jet-application-mark class="block h-9 w-auto" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation Links -->
            <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('dashboard') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                {{ __('Dashboard') }}
            </x-jet-nav-link>
            <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('posts') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('posts')">
                    {{ __('Posts') }}
                </x-jet-nav-link>
            </div>

            <!--Pages Dropdown -->
            <div class="ml-3  mt-4 relative">
                <x-jet-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">

                            <span class="inline-flex rounded-md">
                                <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-500 bg-white hover:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                                     {{ __('Pages') }}

                                    <svg class="ml-2 -mr-0.5 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </span>

                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="content">
                        @foreach(\App\Models\Page::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get() as $page)
                            <x-jet-dropdown-link href="pages/{{__($page['title'])}}">
                                {{ __($page['title']) }}
                            </x-jet-dropdown-link>
                        @endforeach

                    </x-slot>
                </x-jet-dropdown>
                <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('contact-form') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('contact-form')">
                    {{ __('Contact Us') }}
                </x-jet-nav-link>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:ml-6">
            <!-- Teams Dropdown -->
            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures())
                <div class="ml-3 relative">
                    <x-jet-dropdown align="right" width="60">
                        <x-slot name="trigger">
                            <span class="inline-flex rounded-md">
                                <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-50 active:bg-gray-50 transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->currentTeam->name }}

                                    <svg class="ml-2 -mr-0.5 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 3a1 1 0 01.707.293l3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 5.414 7.707 7.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l3-3A1 1 0 0110 3zm-3.707 9.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 14.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 011.414 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-3-3a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </x-slot>

                        <x-slot name="content">
                            <div class="w-60">
                                <!-- Team Management -->
                                <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
                                    {{ __('Manage Team') }}
                                </div>

                                <!-- Team Settings -->
                                <x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('teams.show', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id) }}">
                                    {{ __('Team Settings') }}
                                </x-jet-dropdown-link>

                                @can('create', Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::newTeamModel())
                                    <x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('teams.create') }}">
                                        {{ __('Create New Team') }}
                                    </x-jet-dropdown-link>
                                @endcan

                                <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>

                                <!-- Team Switcher -->
                                <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
                                    {{ __('Switch Teams') }}
                                </div>

                                @foreach (Auth::user()->allTeams() as $team)
                                    <x-jet-switchable-team :team="$team" />
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </x-slot>
                    </x-jet-dropdown>
                </div>
            @endif

            <!-- Settings Dropdown -->
            <div class="ml-3 relative">
                <x-jet-dropdown align="right" width="48">
                    <x-slot name="trigger">
                        @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::managesProfilePhotos())
                            <button class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                                <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover" src="{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" />
                            </button>
                        @else
                            <span class="inline-flex rounded-md">
                                <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm leading-4 font-medium rounded-md text-gray-500 bg-white hover:text-gray-700 focus:outline-none transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}

                                    <svg class="ml-2 -mr-0.5 h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                    </svg>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        @endif
                    </x-slot>

                    <x-slot name="content">
                        <!-- Account Management -->
                        <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
                            {{ __('Manage Account') }}
                        </div>

                        <x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('profile.show') }}">
                            {{ __('Profile') }}
                        </x-jet-dropdown-link>

                        @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasApiFeatures())
                            <x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('api-tokens.index') }}">
                                {{ __('API Tokens') }}
                            </x-jet-dropdown-link>
                        @endif

                        <div class="border-t border-gray-100"></div>

                        <!-- Authentication -->
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <x-jet-dropdown-link href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                     onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                            this.closest('form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Log Out') }}
                            </x-jet-dropdown-link>
                        </form>
                    </x-slot>
                </x-jet-dropdown>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Hamburger -->
        <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center sm:hidden">
            <button @click="open = ! open" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path :class="{'hidden': open, 'inline-flex': ! open }" class="inline-flex" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                    <path :class="{'hidden': ! open, 'inline-flex': open }" class="hidden" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
<div :class="{'block': open, 'hidden': ! open}" class="hidden sm:hidden">
    <div class="pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
        <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('posts') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('posts')">
            {{ __('Posts') }}
        </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
    </div>

    <!-- Responsive Settings Options -->
    <div class="pt-4 pb-1 border-t border-gray-200">
        <div class="flex items-center px-4">
            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::managesProfilePhotos())
                <div class="flex-shrink-0 mr-3">
                    <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full object-cover" src="{{ Auth::user()->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" />
                </div>
            @endif

            <div>
                <div class="font-medium text-base text-gray-800">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>
                <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ Auth::user()->email }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mt-3 space-y-1">
            <!-- Account Management -->
            <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('profile.show') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('profile.show')">
                {{ __('Profile') }}
            </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>

            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasApiFeatures())
                <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('api-tokens.index') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('api-tokens.index')">
                    {{ __('API Tokens') }}
                </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
            @endif

            <!-- Authentication -->
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                @csrf

                <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                this.closest('form').submit();">
                    {{ __('Log Out') }}
                </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
            </form>

            <!-- Team Management -->
            @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::hasTeamFeatures())
                <div class="border-t border-gray-200"></div>

                <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
                    {{ __('Manage Team') }}
                </div>

                <!-- Team Settings -->
                <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('teams.show', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id) }}" :active="request()->routeIs('teams.show')">
                    {{ __('Team Settings') }}
                </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>

                @can('create', Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::newTeamModel())
                    <x-jet-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('teams.create') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('teams.create')">
                        {{ __('Create New Team') }}
                    </x-jet-responsive-nav-link>
                @endcan

                <div class="border-t border-gray-200"></div>

                <!-- Team Switcher -->
                <div class="block px-4 py-2 text-xs text-gray-400">
                    {{ __('Switch Teams') }}
                </div>

                @foreach (Auth::user()->allTeams() as $team)
                    <x-jet-switchable-team :team="$team" component="jet-responsive-nav-link" />
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong div tag.

```
<!--Pages Dropdown -->
<div class="ml-3  mt-4 relative">
    // remove the contact us code from here
</div>

<x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('contact-form') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('contact-form')">
    {{ __('Contact Us') }}
</x-jet-nav-link>
```